# Actor Thread Safety

Tags: multithreading, scala, thread-safety, akka, actor

I have two actors and a Repository, is this safe?

```
def incRepo = {
  val acc = Repo get "account"
  Repo set "account" = acc + 1
}

Actor1 = Actor2 = def receive = {
  case inc => 
    incRepo
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. There are race conditions because the Actors execute in separate threads. ie. Actor1 does the `get` action. Then Actor2 performs the entire `incRepo` several times. Then Actor1 performs the `set` action.

You may want to look into "software transactional memory" with ScalaSTM libs.

You would create a shared `Ref` and make `incRepo` an `atomic` function. When multiple threads enter an `atomic` block, both proceed. The first thread to write to the `Ref` wins, and the loser restarts the `atomic` block from the beginning. Thus, both threads will always work with up-to-date data.

https://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/

STM is an alternative to Locks and Mutexes, but has better concurrency as it uses optimistic non-blocking writes as opposed to blocking on both writes and reads. It is also easier to write and maintain STM code than to do so with locks.